# Auto selecting subnet parameter value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using the following code of Parameters to select the latest AMI. It works as execpted.

```
"Parameters" : {
  "LatestAmiId" : { 
    "Type" : "AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>",
    "Default" : "/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn-ami-hvm-x86_64-ebs"
}},
```

Is there a similar way to select the subnet of default security group?
I do not want to mention the subnet (or security group) like this...

```
"SubnetId": "subnet-e8ecf09c, subnet-aa9dfc90, subnet-ce083188, subnet-718bd259",
```

---

Update:

I am using the following code and it fails with an error "  **Value of property SubnetId must be of type String**"

```
{
"Parameters": {
  "LatestAmiId": {
    "Type": "AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>",     
    "Default": "/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-ebs"
},

  "myKeyPair" : {
    "Description" : "Amazon EC2 Key Pair",
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
  },
  "mySubnetIDs" : {
    "Description" : "Subnet IDs",
    "Type" : "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>"
  },
     "Oksoftaccess":{  
         "Type":"AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>",
         "Default":"myEC2TypeDev"
      },
      "Oksoftsecret":{  
         "Type":"String",
         "Default":"mysecret1"
      }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-subnetid), the “SubnetId” property in the “AWS::EC2::Instance” must be “String” type. However, the [parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) type called “Subnet” is defined as “List” which is a list . EC2 instances can be run in the only one subnet (not multiple subnets).

Change the parameter type to “AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id” as below in your CF template and then try again:

```
    "mySubnetIDs": {
     ...
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id"
     ...
    }
```